# Time for all ants to traverse cube

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider a hypercube of dimension $2n$ with $2^{2n}$ points given by $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{2n})$, where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$. Two points are connected by an edge if and only if they differ in exactly one coordinate. At the beginning, exactly one ant is at each of the vertices of the hypercube.

An ant at point $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{2n})$ wants to get to the point $(a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\ldots,a_{2n},a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. At the beginning of each second, it considers the foremost bit (i.e., the earliest bit from the left) in which its current position differs from its destination, and wants to take the edge to fix that bit. However, each edge can be traversed by at most one ant in a second. The traversal of one edge takes exactly one second.

What is the minimum time for all ants to reach their destination? Asymptotics or bounds are also welcome.

Comment: @Anatoly "At the beginning, an ant is at each of the vertices of the hypercube." That means every vertex has an ant at the beginning.

Comment: "foremost bit" = "with highest index"? "However, each edge can be traversed by at most one ant in a second." Second=step? Does that mean that in each step each one of the ants attemps to move simultaneously, and that two ants can share a point but if so they can't share the movement?

Comment: @leonbloy I've edited -- hope it's clearer. And yes, in each second each one of the ants attempts to move simultaneously, and two ants can share a point but if so they can't share the movement in that second.

Comment: "and wants to take the edge to fix that bit" If it can't, can it transverse another edge, or must it wait?

Comment: @leonbloy It must wait.

Comment: I know that at the beginning there is an ant at each of the vertices. My comment was asking another thing: is the initial numeration of the vertices (i.e., the assignment of $a_1,a_2..a_{2n}$ labels to the vertices) to be considered random?

Comment: @Anatoly All $2n$-bit numbers are present as a label $a_1a_2\ldots a_{2n}$; hence $2^{2n}$ vertices in total.

Comment: Just to be sure, the "AI" of the ants is deterministic? If so, wich ant gets precedence when two ants want to traverse the same edge? If not, you're not directly prescribing the order in wich the ants "fix their bits", right? This would mean we search for an optimal ant AI.

Comment: @AlexR If by "AI" you mean the order in which the ants "fix their bits", that's deterministic. Now, as to which ant gets precedence when two ants want to traverse the same edge, you can choose that (in order to minimize the total time until all ants reach their destination.)

Comment: @simmons Intuitively, I'd guess the precedence is best decided using the number of yet-to-fix bits; in case of a stalemate pick one (at random?)

Comment: @AlexR Maybe. I'd be interested if you could prove that that's optimal.

Comment: @simmons I suspect this might not even be possible, note that for an optimal solution if we may chose where ants go, we certainly make them wait as little as possible while without the choice I think about half of the ants will always have to wait.

Comment: Had a bad answer and deleted it. Now I think I made it right, and undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an ant needs to move to a position where its $1$st and $(n+1)$st bits are exchanged, its $2$nd and $(n+2)$nd bits are exchanged, etc. Sometimes there is not literally a need to exchange bits in position pairs like this, if they already match. But consider points like $(1,1,0,0)$ when $n=2$. Ants starting at a point like this will have to have all their bits flipped to reach their destination. So $2n$ is a lower bound on total steps taken for the entire march of ants. But we can actually accomplish the march in $2n$ steps, as described below.

Some ants start out at their final destination. For example, with $n=2$, the ant at $(0,1,0,1)$ is already where it needs to be. (There are $2^n$ such ants, corresponding to any sequence for the first $n$ coordinates, repeated for the last $n$ coordinates.) Call these points "level $0$". In general, we say that a point is at "level $k$" if there are $k$ pairs of bit positions $i$ and $i+n$ that don't match (and so need to be exchanged if an ant starts there). The highest level is level $n$, since we could leave a point's first $n$ bits alone and toggle its last $n$ bits to make $n$ such pairs.)

Ants who start in positions $(0,a,b,\ldots\big|0,z,y,\ldots)$ or $(1,a,b,\ldots\big|1,z,y,\ldots)$ do not need the $1$st or $(n+1)$st bits flipped in comparison to their final destination. But ants who start in $(0,a,b,\ldots\big|1,z,y,\ldots)$ or $(1,a,b,\ldots\big|0,z,y,\ldots)$ need *both* of these positions flipped.

- Step $1$: For all ants who need to flip the bits in positions $1$ and $n+1$, have them walk to the point that flips the first bit. Note that this reduces the level of the point that the ant is standing at, because now the bits at positions $1$ and $n+1$ are equal. Since these ants all start in different places, there is no repeated use of an edge where two ants walked it in the same direction. Since this movement was universally a reduction in level, there was no repeated use of an edge from two ants walking in opposite directions.
- Step $2$: For the ants who just moved in Step $1$, have them walk to the point that flips the $(n+1)$st bit. This movement will now raise the level of where these ants are standing. The combination of these two steps permutes the positions of these ants who needed their $1$st and $(n+1)$st bits flipped. (An ant who was at $(0,a,b,\ldots\big|1,z,y,\ldots)$ is now at $(1,a,b,\ldots\big|0,z,y,\ldots)$ and vice versa). So we are back in a state where each point on the hypercube has one ant. Therefore no two ants just walked the same edge in the same direction. And again the universal (this time upward) change in level implies no two ants shared an edge walking in opposite directions either.
- Step $3$, $4$: Repeat steps $1$ and $2$ but applied to the $2$nd and $(n+2)$nd bits. Since we ended step $2$ with one ant on each point, we will again execute movement without any two ants using the same edge at the same time.
- Step $5$, $6$: Repeat, applied to the $3$rd and $(n+3)$rd bits.
- ...
- Step $2n-1$, $2n$: Repeat, applied to the $n$th and $2n$th bits.

And now, after $2n$ steps, every ant has reached its final destination. As noted before, $2n$ is a lower bound for a complete march of the ants to their destinations, but now we see it is an upper bound for the most efficient march as well.

Comment: Read the discussion carefully and see that you aren't allowed to alter the sequence in wich the ants attempt to toggle their bits, thus step 2 is invalid. You may only chose _wich ant_ gets precedence on a "collision edge".

Comment: Relevant quote by @simmons: (at)AlexR If by "AI" you mean the order in which the ants "fix their bits", that's deterministic. Now, as to which ant gets precedence when two ants want to traverse the same edge, you can choose that (in order to minimize the total time until all ants reach their destination.)

Comment: @AlexR I interpret "that's deterministic" to mean that I, as the author of the algorithm, may determine the order that they fix their bits. As opposed to a process where an ant chooses a bit to flip based on some kind of random process. Perhaps OP can clarify.

Comment: @alex.jordan Actually I meant the interpretation that AlexR gave. However, your answer is also very nice (for your interpretation), so please keep it. :)

Comment: OK, but can you help me understand what you want ants to do? They are supposed to try to toggle their first bit first, if that is needed? And once they have accomplished that, then they are supposed to attempt to toggle their second bit (if needed)? And if they have to wait because of an edge conflict, then they wait until they can toggle their second bit without conflict?

Comment: @alex.jordan The answer is "yes" to all of your questions. If multiple ants are waiting to use the same edge, then you (as the author of the algorithm) can decide which ant gets to go first and which ant has to wait.

Comment: Suppose it is possible for an ant to toggle their $k$th bit, uninhibited by any edge conflict. Can I, as the author of the algorithm, make that ant stay put a little longer? The reason for doing so would be to control more tightly which ants are where to prevent edge conflicts.

Comment: @alex.jordan If an ant can move, making it move is always at least as good as making it stay put, since it has to move along that edge anyway. But if it helps in your analysis to have the ant stay put, of course you can have it that way.